# To how many operating systems has Mathematica been ported?

Tags: windows, mac-os-x, linux, raspberry-pi

Does Wolfram Mathematica only work with the Windows operating system?

Comment: Nope, also on Linux and macOS. And on the Raspberry Pi...

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html